# Bootstrap carousel doesn't start on-load and sliding stops with hover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hover, slider, carousel

I have this code in HTML. The whole section is in id="main-slider". The carousel doesn't slide unless I click on the arrow and it works perfectly after that. Another problem which I'm facing is that the slider is a full page slider. By default, bootstrap stops sliding when hovered. I do not want this effect to take place. To solve both, I gave the jQuery function to overwrite this, but nothing seems to work. After spending 6 hours reading and trying almost everything in Github and at this place, finally decided to get help here.

```
    <section id="main-slider">
    <div class="carousel slide">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators ">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#main-slider"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#main-slider"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#main-slider"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#main-slider"></li>
      </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(images/slider1.jpg)">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="carousel-content centered">
                <div class="center" id="text-position"> <!-- self defined class in css-->
                  <h2></h2>
                    <p></p>
                      <a class="btn btn-md-primary></a>
                </div> <!-- /center -->
              </div> <!-- /carousel-content -->
            </div> <!-- /col-sm -->
          </div> <!-- /row -->
        </div> <!-- /container -->
      </div> <!-- /item active -->
    <!--I have 3 more similar rows-->
    </div> <!-- carousel ends -->

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
    $('#main-slider.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 2000,
        pause: false
        });
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: Could you set this up on jsfiddle or codepen so we can see a 'working' example

Comment: It seems to work with this. Please find the link here http://jsfiddle.net/u8j9925w/3/

Comment: auto sliding works fine now.. included this JavaScript at the end.. still facing problem with slider stop with mouse hover (full page slider website)..
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        $("#main-slider").carousel();
    })();
</script>

Comment: Your JSFiddle markup and javascript is notably different to the above. Be sure to follow the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) on how to set up the carousel carefully, this is the best way to get it working to start with. Then you can style it as you need from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using the Javascript initialiser, have you tried using the `data-` attributes method? e.g.

```
<div class="carousel slide wet-asphalt" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000" data-pause="false">
```

Don't forget to remove your Javascript initialiser.